# Android Google Maps sliding animation to Marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using Google Maps Api and 'm using custom marker. I want to set sliding animation to marker.

So user if click to marker, a part of marker sliding hide under the remaining part. When the part of hidden if click animation will reversed.

So like this as images :

[image: full_marker_cengiz]
    to 
[image: pure_marker_cengiz]

**left_to_right_anim.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

**right_to_left.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

And I tried in onMapReady method:

```
 mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(marker -> {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
            if (!isMarkerPure) {
                AnimationUtil.slideRightToLeft(mCurrLocationMarker, rootView.getContext());
                mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions.position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromBitmap(getPureMarker(R.drawable.cengiz)))
                        .anchor(0.5f, anchorY));

                isMarkerPure = true;
            } else {
                AnimationUtil.slideLeftToRight(mCurrLocationMarker, rootView.getContext());
                mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions.position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromBitmap(getMarkerBitmapFromView(R.drawable.cengiz, locName, name)))
                        .anchor(0.125f, anchorY));

                isMarkerPure = false;
            }
            return false;
        });
```

But animation didn't happen. Has anyone ever done anything like that before?

Comment: You remove the marker before starting animation - how about removing the marker when the animation completes - then continue with addMarker code.

Comment: @Andy it's probably a handle to the last one marker added ...nevertheless it might throw NPE.